# Node JS session settings

Tags: node.js, session

I do come from php background and if i set a session, it will be specific to the user. so while developing i can act as two user, opening the app in normal mode and incognito mode, and verify the communication between server and db update.

Now i am developing an application with Nodejs. Either i have misunderstood the express-session with PHP session or i didnt configure it properly. If i login as a user in normal window and open incognito window, the session is getting reset.

**app.js**

```
    var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var http = require('http');
var reload = require('reload');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard');
var search = require('./routes/search');
var profile = require('./routes/profile');
var ajax = require('./routes/admin-ajax');
var logout = require('./routes/logout');



var app = express();


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/dashboard', dashboard);
app.use('/search', search);
app.use('/profile', profile);
app.use('/admin-ajax', ajax);
app.use('/logout', logout);




app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/moment/min')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/lodash')); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/font-awesome/css')); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/animate.css')); 

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/datatables.net/js')); 
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js')); 
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css')); 






// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


var server = http.createServer(app)

reload(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
 console.log('Web server listening on port ' + app.get('port'))
});





module.exports = app;
```

**Login Verification**

```
user.verify_login = (req, res, next)=>{
    let query = {$and:[{mobile:{$eq:req.body.mobile}}, {otp:{$eq:_.toString(req.body.otp)}}]}
    db.connect(function(err, dbconnect){
        if(err)
            return res.status(404).send({message:'Error connecting db'});
        dbconnect.collection('users').findOne(query, function(err, result){
            if(err || _.isEmpty(result))
                return res.send({success:false, message:'Mobile OTP doesnot match'});
            result.success = true;
            req.session.user = result; // I am storing session value here
            return res.send({success:true, redirect:'/dashboard'});
        })
    });
}
```

As i have almost done with my codes, i am looking for an answer like,

1. if i host it, will the session be renewed everytime a user tries to use the app.
2. If no, is the issue becos of incognito mode. if yes, how to overcome it.

Hope i made the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're doing to test your application, but to answer your main question, no session is still per user and will not reset anytime any user logs in.

That said, the behavior you're describing sounds off to me, so you likely have a bug in your code somewhere.  I'm not seeing where you actually mount your routes in the code you posted, so it's difficult to see, but there are two common issues I've seen with folks new to express:

1) `app.use` order matters.  So, if you mount your routes before mounting your session, you'll see weirdness.

2) Setting the `secure` attribute on the session config is recommended for production, but will make it look like session isn't working in development because dev sites are generally not served over https.

Comment: The scenario is simple. Lets say a user posts a question and another user answers it. So as user-1 i opened chrome and posted a question. And for user-2 i pressed Ctrl+N (incognito mode) and tried to login as user-2. But my user-1 session is lost.

Comment: I have updated my full app.js file. Please advise if any changes i need to make.

Comment: Not that I can see from what you have posted.  Have you tried logging in from two different browsers (eg chrome and Firefox) to eliminate any vagaries around Incognito mode?

Comment: Actually, can you also post your login route code? Are you using Passport or did you invent your own logic for handling user state?

Comment: I am not using passport. I have updated the login route code. Where i compare mobile number and otp and if it matches, the user is stored in req.session.user

Comment: Sir, as a last help, can u please take a look into http://matrimony.fr.openode.io where when you click 5-6 times on left flyout menu, the session expired message is thrown. To login use 9952762769, otp will be auto placed.